# Is there an easy way to quickly gain stars/coins in Super Mario 3D Land?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

Is there an easier way to collect star/coins to unlock all the way to Bowser, and if so how? I have already collected 72 but cant seem to get the rest. Please help. :)

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE, thanks for posting :)  This question is a little broad, we don't know what you've done and what you haven't.  Is there some specific coin/star/level that's giving you trouble?  Trying to guess what you're missing and tell you how to get them is going to make any answer really difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters, I would usually go look for the little nooks and crannies in a level, such as a wall which may have bricks you can break with a tanooki suit or by crouching under small holes that lead to rooms(Usually they are 1Ups but they can be paths to coins). Next EXPLORE as i would climb the walls of levels and follow the paths until something appears, and always use the binoculars, as you can spot out toad, and when you zoom up to him, he will toss a coin and you can collect it at the designated area. There may be more ways, but these helped me find the majority of all the coins. 
Hoped this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Mystery boxes to get star coins. All you have to do is to play the level when it opens, kill all of the enemies, and usually, you get a star coin and a bunch of coins.